# Date Difference Calculations between Excel and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, date

I'm using Excel 2013 and SQL Server 2014. I'd like to know why I get two different results when calculating date differences on the same dates:

**Excel:**

[image]

```
C2=IF(B2="",0,(DATE(YEAR(B2),MONTH(B2),DAY(B2))-DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),DAY(A2)) + TIME(HOUR(B2),MINUTE(B2),SECOND(B2))-TIME(HOUR(A2),MINUTE(A2),SECOND(A2)))*24)
```

**SQL Server:**

```
--Ex 1:
cast(datediff(MINUTE, '2015-11-04 13:38:20.000', '2015-11-04 16:15:00.000') as float) / 60
```

Result:  2.61666666666667

```
--Ex 2:
cast(datediff(MINUTE, '2015-11-04 13:38:20.000', '2015-11-04 16:15:00.000') as decimal(15, 5)) / 60
```

Result: 2.61666666

Thank you.

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is often not exact in a programming language, less often so between languages.  Do you really need sub millisecond precision?

Comment: Appreciate the quick response.  Yes, I'm learning lots about using floating point with calculations.  I received this data from client, I don't think the millisecond precision is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in your SQL code you are taking the difference in minutes, which rounds the difference up to the nearest minute. In this case, 157 minutes. If you take the difference in seconds, and divide by 60, you will see that the actual difference is 156.6666... minutes.

Try this:

```
SELECT cast(datediff(s, '2015-11-04 13:38:20.000', '2015-11-04 16:15:00.000') AS DECIMAL(38,18)) / 3600
```

That returns `2.611111111111111111`, the same as in Excel.